# IBM MQ Client 9.0 installation failed on Window 7 Professional SP1

Tags: ibm-mq, xms

**System Configuration:**
Windows 7 professional SP1 (64 bit)

1. Uninstalled MQ Client 7.5
2. Later tried installing MQ Client 9.0, downloaded from [here](https://www-945.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/downloadFixes?parent=ibm~WebSphere&product=ibm/WebSphere/WebSphere%20MQ&release=9.0&platform=All&function=fixId&fixids=9.0.0.0-IBM-MQC-Win64&includeRequisites=1&includeSupersedes=0&downloadMethod=http). 
   But installation after running for 2 minutes, failed in the end with the below error. I had choose default setup components.

> Blockquote
>   Error 1713. IBM MQ (Installation1) cannot install one of its required products. Contact your technical support group.

3. Looked into temp folder installation log files. The installation has failed @ CustomAction "iwiInstall32bitRuntime".

> MSI (s) (2C:A0) [17:36:55:139]: Note: 1: 2203 2: C:\PATH \IBM
>   MQ\9.0.0.0-IBM-MQC-Win64\Windows\msi\IBM MQ 32bitSupport.msi 3:
>   -2147287038
>
> CustomAction iwiInstall32bitRuntime returned actual error code 2 (note
>   this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
>
> MSI (s) (2C:1C) [17:36:55:139]: Note: 1: 1713 2: IBM MQ
>   (Installation1) 3: 1631
>
> Info 2835.The control ErrorIcon was not found on dialog SetupError.
>
> Error 1713.IBM MQ (Installation1) cannot install one of its required
>   products. Contact your technical support group.  System Error: 1631.
>
> MSI (s) (2C:1C) [17:37:54:336]: Product: IBM MQ (Installation1) --
>   Error 1713.IBM MQ (Installation1) cannot install one of its required
>   products. Contact your technical support group.  System Error: 1631.
>
> Action ended 17:37:54: iwiInstall32bitRuntime. Return value 3.

Any RESOLUTION for this error?

Comment: Turn on MSI logging ( https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/223300 ) and see what's happening inside the 32 bit runtime installer. Basically the main product install spawns a 32 and a 64 bit C runtime installer to lay down the Microsoft C runtimes it needs, and one of those is failing. If you use that fixit, each msi install generates a msi*.log in the %TEMP% directory, and one should be for the C runtime - see if you can see anything obvious or put that plus the main installer log somewhere.   Chances are the C runtime is badly/incorrectly installed, but without seeing a log its hard to tell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution here https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/275503/mq-install-on-windows-fails-with-rc1713.html

> The 9.0.0.0-IBM-MQC-Win64.zip file has the 32-bit and 64-bit compiler runtime MSI files in the wrong location relative to where Setup (IBM MQ.msi) is looking for them.
>
> To workaround this issue, copy "%mq_install_media_path%\Windows\MSI\x86\IBM MQ 32bitSupport.msi" to "%mq_install_media_path%\Windows\MSI\", and copy "%mq_install_media_path%\Windows\MSI\x64\IBM MQ 64bitSupport.msi" to "%mq_install_media_path%\Windows\MSI\".
>
> (where %mq_install_media_path% contains the unzipped 9.0.0.0-IBM-MQC-Win64.zip files).